# Duda con xml y laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xml

Buenas, soy nuevo con el framework,tengo una duda con respecto a un xml que estoy haciendo en un proyecto que esta laravel, el detalle es que lo estoy haciendo enteramente con php pero cuando quiero visualizar lo que he hecho, no puedo. acá dejo mi código

```
    <?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/amDG?format=xml"
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

for ($i  = 0;$i<10; $i++){
  $id = $xml->entry[$i]->id;
  $publi = $xml->entry[$i]->published;
  $upda = $xml->entry[$i]->updated;
  $title = $xml->entry[$i]->title;
  $content = $xml->entry[$i]->content
  $link =$xml->entry[$i]->link;
  $name = $xml->entry[$i]->author->name;
  $uri =  $xml.->entry[$i]->author->uri;
  $mail =  $xml.->entry[$i]->author->email;
  $html .="<div>
  <h1>$title</h1>
  <h3>
  <a><spam>$link</spam></a>
  <div>"update:"$upda &nbsp;&nbsp; "published:"$published </div>
  <br>
  <div>$content</div>
  <br>
  <div><spam>$name</spam></div>
  <br>
  <div>$uri</div>
  <div>$mail</div>  
  </h3>

  </div>";
}
echo $html;
 ?>
```

solo agregue el archivo en la carpeta donde estoy trabajando. no se si tengo que agregar alguna función para la vista en otro lado, tengo esa duda, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo correcto es utilizar un contralador y una vista para mostrar la información. Si utilizas `echo` estás ignorando por completo el Framework. :/

Comment: Eso olvide ponerlo, no tengo controlador, solo el modelo, eso me tiene algo confundido. @Jemonge

Comment: Por curiosidad, en cuál carpeta agregó ese código?

Comment: en una que esta fuera de donde están las carpetas de el framework, pero, se usa uno de los modelos, así me dejaron el proyecto. @Jemonge

Comment: Ummm, estás algo mal, lo mínimo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente: **1.** Crear un [controlador](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers) con el código php que obtiene el XML. **2.** Crear la [vista](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views) que tendrá el código HTML encargado de mostrar la información del XML. Esta vista será llamada por el controlador. **3.** Crear una [ruta](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing) para llamar al controlador cuando ingreses al enlace que definas.

Comment: @Jemonge te sugiero que lo escribas (más detallado) como respuesta, puede ayudar a otras personas en el futuro, te daré mi +1

Comment: @Shaz respuesta agregada. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera en que lo estás programando no es correcta para el Framework. Lo mínimo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

**1.** Crear un [controlador](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers) con el código php que obtiene el XML. Los controladores se guardan en la carpeta `app/Http/Controllers`. Le puedes poner a tu archivo el nombre `XmlController.php` y tendría un código similar a este:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class XmlController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $url = "http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/amDG?format=xml";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        /* Aquí lo mejor es manipular la información de tu XML de acuerdo a lo que se mostrará en la vista */

        return view('xml', ['xmlContent' => $xml]);
    }
}
```

**2.** Crear la [vista](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views) que tendrá el código HTML encargado de mostrar la información del XML. Esta vista será llamada por el controlador. Las vistas se guardan en la carpeta `resources/views/` y deberás ponerle el nombre `xml.blade.php` . El código sería algo así:

```
@foreach ($xmlContent as $item)
    <h2>{{ $item->title }}</h2>
    <div>
        <a><spam>{{ $item->link }}</spam></a>
        <div>update: {{ $item->updated }} published: {{ $item->published }}</div>
        <br>
        <div>{{ $item->content }}</div>
        <br>
        <div><spam>{{ $item->name }}</spam></div>
        <br>
        <div>{{ $item->uri }}</div>
        <div>{{ $item->email }}</div>  
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**3.** Crear una [ruta](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing) para llamar al controlador cuando ingreses al enlace que definas. Las rutas se guardan en el archivo `routes/web.php`. Ahí puedes agregar tu nueva ruta que llamará el controlador:

```
Route::get('/xml', 'XmlController@show');
```

Comment: No me funciona amigo, de verdad ya no se que hacer.

Comment: Te muestra algún error?

Comment: "FatalErrorException in XmlController.php line 14: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)" , intente regresando solo un mensaje simple a ver si mostraba algo pero tampoco. @Jemonge

Comment: Para mostrar un mensaje puedes utilizar `dd()`. La función sería así `public function show(){ dd('Controlador llamado'); }`. Qué código tienes en la línea 14 y la que está antes de esa?

Comment: ahorita tengo esto 
{
    if($response=='404'){
código que estaba probando para ver
  }
}

pero tenia esto antes de colocar lo de arriba 

{return view("hola");}

Comment: listooo! resolví el problema, con algo de ayuda , era un *;* que no había colocado , de verdad no se como se me pasó. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!